# Representation of 1D time series for use in transformers

Tags: time-series, transformer

I am working on a transformer where the encoder is given a sentence. However, the decoder is given 1D time series data (so, a single 1xm row vector). Given that the encoder is given n 350 dimensional vectors, should I just let the output of the encoder be a 1xm matrix? Or, is there some other way of representing 1D time series data I should look at?